# Printing Chinese Characters on POS Receipt using RawPrinterHelper

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I'm having trouble printing Chinese characters on receipt using RawPrinterHelper. I am able to print my receipt correctly using PrintDocument but only as XPS and txt.

The string is converted to a byte array which is sent to the RawPrinterHelper. The problem is that one chinese character is equal to 3 bytes. So when it is printed, its displays 3 random characters.

Ex: 
Chinese character is **大** when converted to byte is **{229,164,167}** and when printed:  **å¤§**

The receipt printer that i use for printing is : EPSON TM-u220 and POSTECH RP76III

Comment: Seems you've string encoding problem (UTF-8/Unicode treated as ANSI string). Can you give some relevant code pieces & the output given by `RawPrinterHelper`?

Comment: You'll have to read the programming manual.  There is a command that switches the active character set.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to print chinese characters you have to enable Chinese mode. I'm doing it with Java but probably it should be similar.

```
addTwoArrays(byteArrayOf(0x1c,0x26), toBytes(chineseText,"CP936"))
```

You can find more about this on printer specs. 
The above command is: FS &

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58881605/esc-pos-command-for-printing-chinese-character. Thank you so much!